# VSCode command line parameters

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can I access to VSCode command line parameters via extension? E.g., as Extension's predefined variable(like ${file}), as parameter for special constructor for Extension or auto-running task?
For example, if I start VSCode like:

```
code --myParam 10
```

Can I access the value of 'myParam' from my own extension or is there any other way to pass some parameter inside to the extension from command line options?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer by myself.
The secret was that VSCode [can be launched](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls) by special URL, where you can add your own query parameters and then [handle them](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#UriHandler) in your extension.
Example of the URL:

```
vscode://sergey.custom-plugin/customCommand?args={"param1":1, "param2":"cusomOption"}
```

Arguments can be passed at JSON format without any limitations.
For this, we need to implement *vscode.UriHandler*.
Example of such a realization can be found[here](https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-debug-launcher).
Hope this info can be helpful to someone.